# Saving comma delimited data from a web application

Tags: html, sql-server, t-sql, web-applications

I am using ColdFusion 10, but this question can be true for any web-application. I am trying to save a set of checkboxes *with the same name*. When they are posted, the form variable stores them as a comma separated list of IDs. Normally I would receive it as a varchar parameter in a storedprocedure and will parse them in t-sql to get to the individual values and inserting them to a table. I have been using this technique for quite some time.

I just want to check with you guys if there is any newer way of doing this. Basically what I am asking is how do you save a bunch of html checkboxes into a database table elegantly without using some kind of grunt code, like parsing.

Comment: Depends on the source the checkbox values. If they are generated from a database query, the simplest method is `INSERT/SELECT`. `SELECT` the checked values by passing the form field into an `IN (...)` clause. Then `INSERT` them into the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this will work. First convert to xml and then use xml to insert into table:http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10300/xquery-lab-19-how-to-parse-a-delimited-string.aspx

Comment: Unless I am reading this post incorrectly, it is inserting all company codes for a single company into one column, resulting in denormalized data. This is not a very good way to store data like this.

Comment: I think he just used a table to demonstrate the concept. Using a variable would have been better, but .. oh well. In any case, that same technique can be used to split a "list" from CF.

Comment: @Aamir - Since links to tend to break over time, it would be helpful to update your answer to include a CF example as well.

Answer (score 1):

I might use `listToArray( form.fieldname )` to turn the list into an array, then loop over the array to do inserts.

Comment: Thank you Scott, but this seems like a Coldfusion solution. I am already using it and for that I don't even have to convert list to array. I can loop directly over the list and do the inserts. I was looking for a T-sql solution irrespective of the web application platform. I don't know if its you or someone else who down-voted my T-Sql solution I already posted. Please undo it. Thanks

Comment: Why not simply loop through the list instead of converting it to an array first?

Comment: @Aamir why would you tag the question as 'ColdFusion' if you were not looking for a ColdFusion answer?

Comment: @DanBracuk it is faster to turn list to array and loop over the resulting array than to loop over a list in ColdFusion.

Comment: @ScottStroz My bad. I shouldn't have tagged it Coldfusion. I simply mentioned it as one of the app servers I was using, but it could be anything. Thanks for your CF solution anyways